# Fonts: Is changing the default font a good practice?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've searched PW, but I saw that no one has asked specifically yet. Is changing the default font a good practice for the main body font? What are the pros and cons to using different fonts? This includes only font families, and excludes size, color, decoration, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See these two SitePoint articles: [The Anatomy of Web Fonts](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/anatomy-web-fonts) and [Eight Definitive Font Stacks](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/eight-definitive-font-stacks).

Basically it is ok to change the font as long as you choose fonts that are available to your users and are readable. It's very normal to do this and allows your website to be more appealing and even more usable if done properly.